# Right triangle where the perimeter = area*k

Tags: diophantine-equations, triangles

I was doodling on some piece of paper a problem that sprung into my mind. After a few minutes of resultless tries, I advanced to try to solve the problem using computer based means.

The problem stated is

> Does a right angle triangle with integer sides such that
>     $$P = A\cdot k \quad \quad \text{or} \quad \quad k\cdot P = A$$ where $(P , \ A , \ k )\in \mathbb{N}$ exist?

(Here P is the perimeter of the triangle. Sum of the sides. And A is the area of the triangle. a*b/2 in a triangle with a b c and c is the hypotenuse)

Obviously for the simple cases such triangles exists. For an example 
when

$ A=2P \qquad $ the triangle $12,16,20$ works

$ A=P  \qquad \; \; $ the triangle $6,8,10$ works

$2A=P  \qquad $ the triangle $3,4,5$ works

I tried solving this by hand, first for the special case where $2P=A$. This ended up giving me

$$ \frac{a \cdot b}{2} = A $$

and

$$ P = \frac{A}{2} = \frac{a \cdot b}{4} \qquad \text{also} \qquad P = a + b + c  $$

So

$$ \frac{ab}{4} = a + b + c $$

By knowing that this is a right angle this leads to the equation (Using the Pythagorean theorem)

$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $$

Now we have two equations and three unknowns, which also needs to be integers! Sadly I was not able to continue from here. I have only learned how to solve linear Diophantine equations. Not a system of nonlinear Diophantine equations.

Just to restate my question below =)

> Is there a right angle triangle with integer sides such that
>     $$P = A\cdot k \quad \quad \text{or} \quad \quad k\cdot P = A$$ where $(P , \ A , \ k )\in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Regards, Werner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have the following relations:
$$P=a+b+c,\quad 2A=ab,\quad a^2+b^2=c^2$$

In fact, there is one more that is implicit: the triangle inequality $a+b>c$ (which follows from $a^2+b^2=c^2$). We wish to relate the first and second relations, and so after staring at the problem for a while we realize the correct course of action is to multiply $P$ by $a+b-c$ (the latter guaranteed to be positive by the triangle inequality). This gives:

$$\begin{align}P(a+b-c)&=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)=(a+b)^2-c^2\\
&=a^2+b^2+2ab-c^2=2ab=4A
\end{align}$$

Hence in general for a right triangle we have $k=A/P=(a+b-c)/4$, so the question boils down to when the difference between the sum of the lengths of the legs and the length of the hypothenuse divides or is divisible by $4$, for a right triangle with integer side-lengths.

Here we actually need to generate pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a,b,c$ are integers and $a^2+b^2=c^2$; the wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Geometry_of_Euclid.27s_formula) gives a good picture of Euclid's formula that I recommend thinking through. Euclid's formula is the following:

$$a=m^2-n^2,\quad b=2mn\quad c=m^2+n^2$$ for integers $m>n$.

Then the quantity $a+b-c$ is $m^2-n^2+2mn-m^2-n^2=2n(m-n)$, so $A/P=k=n(m-n)/2$. The options are now that either $2$ divides $n$ or $2$ divides $m-n$, so we either have $n=2d$ and $m=k/d+2d$ or $n=d$ and $m=2(k/d)+d$ for divisors $d$ of $k$.

(to get $P/A=k$ we need $2n(m-n)$ to divide $4$, so $n(m-n)$ must divide $2$, thus $n=1$, $m=2$, $n=1$, $m=3$, and $n=2$, $m=3$ are the only solutions, giving us $(3,4,5)$, $(8,6,10)$, $(5,12,13)$ with $k=2,1,2$ being the only possibilities).

Comment: +1 for staring at problem solution method

Answer (score 3):

There is a method of generating all of the Pythagorean triples, that goes back in principle at least to the time of Euclid.  You may find the details in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) interesting.

As a brief summary, apart from the order that the two legs are listed, all Pythagorean triples $(x,y,z)$ have the shape
$$x=\lambda(m^2-n^2),\qquad y=\lambda(2mn), \qquad z=\lambda(m^2+n^2),\qquad (\ast)$$
where $m$, $n$, and $\lambda$ are positive integers.

For a triangle as described in $(\ast)$, we have $P=\lambda(2m^2+2mn)$ and $A=\lambda^2mn(m^2-n^2)$.
So your equations (i) $P=kA$ and (ii) $A=kP$ can be rewritten as

(i) $\lambda(2m^2+2mn)=k\lambda^2mn(m^2-n^2)$ and

(ii) $k\lambda(2m^2+2mn)=\lambda^2mn(m^2-n^2)$.

Equation (i) quickly collapses. Cancellation gives $k\lambda n(m-n)=2$, and the list of solutions is short.  There are two possibilities, $k=2$ and $k=1$. If $k=2$, then $\lambda=1$ and $m=2$, $n=1$, which gives your example $(3,4,5)$. If $k=1$, then $\lambda=2$, $m=2$, $n=1$ or $\lambda=1$, $m=3$, $n=1$, or $\lambda=1$, $m=3$, $n=2$. We obtain the examples $(6,8,10)$ and $(5,12, 13)$. That's all.

Equation (ii) is more interesting. Cancellation gives 
$$\lambda n(m-n)=2k. \qquad(\ast\ast)$$
For any $k$, we can find a solution, for example by putting $\lambda=1$, $n=2k$, and $m=2k+1$.  Or, less interestingly, we can put $\lambda=k$, $m=2$, $n=1$, which gives a scaled version of the familiar $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle.

For given $k$, we can find an explicit way to generate all solutions of $(\ast\ast)$, and to obtain a count of them.  For any fixed $k$, there are only finitely many solutions.  Roughly speaking, if $k$ has many divisors then there are many solutions, since we generate the solutions by looking at factors of $2k$.

Comment: I am currently working on this particular problem, i notice that (3,4,5) is a solution, but why. With this Pythagorean triple the perimeter doesn't equal to the area. So my question is, How does this Pythagorean is a solution. thanks

Comment: The answer says in particular that though for the $3$-$4$-$5$ the perimeter is not equal to the area, for a close relative of the $3$-$4$-$5$ it is. For look at $3k$-$4k$-$5k$. Perimeter is $12k$, area is $6k^2$. Taking $k=2$ makes things work, so for the $6$-$8$-$10$ perimeter equals area.

Comment: so you are pretty much saying that 3,4,5 is like a base case in which i can  use to get other pythagorean triples

Comment: But there are plenty of other base cases. The question and answer discussed a more general problem, where $k$ had another meaning. So I am now sorry I used $k$ in my last comment, use $w$ instead. Same result.

Comment: cool thanks man, that was a smooth result

Answer (score 1):

If you choose positive integers $a$ and $b$, you can make a right triangle with sides
$a^2-b^2\text{, } 2ab \text{ and } a^2+b^2,$
and all right triangles can be found this way by varying the values of $a$ and $b$.

If we have such a triangle, its area is
$$\frac{1}{2}(a^2-b^2)\times 2ab = ab(a^2-b^2)$$
and its perimeter is 
$$a^2-b^2 + 2ab + a^2+b^2 = 2a(a+b).$$

For the first part of your question we want to set
$$ab(a^2-b^2)\times k = 2a(a+b).$$
We can write this as
$$ab(a-b)(a+b) = 2a(a+b)$$
and then cancel the $a$ and the $(a+b)$ on each side (neither are zero so it's ok) and get
$$b(a-b)k = 2\quad\text{, and finally}$$
$$k = \frac{2}{b(a-b)}.$$

We want $k$ to be an integer, so it can only be 1 or 2.
If $k=1$ , $b(a-b)$ must equal $2$ and this can happen in two ways: when $a=3\text{ and }b=2$, which produces the 5-12-13 triangle, and when $a=3$ and $b=1$, which produces the 6-8-10 triangle.
If $k=2$ , $b(a-b)$ must equal $1$ and the only way this can happen is when $a=2\text{ and }b=1$. These values of $a$ and $b$ produce the 3-4-5 triangle.

For the second part of your question we want to set
$$ab(a^2-b^2) = 2a(a+b)\times k.$$
We can reduce this as before and arrive at
$$k = \frac{b(a-b)}{2}.$$
There are lots of different values of $a$ and $b$ that make $k$ an integer.

Comment: Minor comment: Not all Pythagorean triangles can be found in this way. The smallest counterexample is $(9,12,15)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can find Pythagorean triples for any ratio $R$ of area/perimeter by finding the $m,n$ integers that represent them using the following formula which includes a difined finite search for values of $m$. Note, all the known ratios are multiples of $0.5$.

$$n=\frac{m\pm \sqrt{m^2-8R}}{2}\text{ where }\lceil\sqrt{8R}\space \rceil \le m \le 2R+1$$

Example: For $R=0.5\quad \sqrt{8*0.5}=2\le m \le (2*0.5+1)=2$

$$n=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{2^2-8*0.5}}{2}=1\qquad f(2,1)=(3,4,5)$$
These triples usually occur in pairs and sometimes more than one pair.

$$R=1\rightarrow 3\le m \le 3\quad f(3,2)=(5,12,13)\quad f(3,1)=(8,6,10)$$

$$R=2\rightarrow 4\le m \le 5\quad f(4,2)=(12,16,20)\quad f(5,4)=(9,40,41)\quad f(5,1)=(24,10,26)$$

$$R=3\rightarrow 4\le m \le 7\quad f(5,3)=(16,30,34)\quad f(5,2)=(21,20,29)\quad f(7,6)=(13,84,85)\quad f(7,1)=(48,14,50)$$

Aside: we can always find one primitive triple for a given $R$ if we let $(m,n)=(2R+1,2R)$.